# when depthwise separable convolution should be preferred over normal convolution?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-network, convolution, image-preprocessing

As a novice in the realm of deep learning, I recently learned about Depthwise Separable Convolution. I have seen some tutorials and articles about it on internet, and in all of them the author mentioned that in some cases it is better to use Depthwise Separable Convolution; however, these cases are not mentioned.

Now, my question is: when should we use Depthwise Separable Convolution and when should we not? Also, what items should be considered when we would like to decide if we need normal convolution or depthwise separable convolution?

Comment: Here's a good resource to learn about separable (and depthwise separable) convolutions: https://towardsdatascience.com/a-basic-introduction-to-separable-convolutions-b99ec3102728